# Reading ReStructured text on android?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean, ebooks

I found/got referred to  this book : http://www.djangobook.com/

Which had a [github page having files in the .rst(ReStructuredText) format](https://github.com/jacobian/djangobook.com).

What is a format that I can compile this to so that it can be read by some app on an android device and how?

Answer (score 1):

[rst2pdf](https://code.google.com/p/rst2pdf/) is an application that can be used to compile Restructured text into pdf.

To read a pdf on your android should be trivial-ish. Grab any pdf reader.